# Integration testing Hive jobs

Tags: java, testing, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I'm trying to write a non-trivial Hive job using the Hive Thrift and JDBC interfaces, and I'm having trouble setting up a decent JUnit test. By non-trivial, I mean that the job results in at least one MapReduce stage, as opposed to only dealing with the metastore.

The test should fire up a Hive server, load some data into a table, run some non-trivial query on that table, and check the results.

I've wired up a Spring context according to the [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-hadoop/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/hive.html). However, the job fails on the MapReduce phase, complaining that no Hadoop binary exists:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/hadoop" (in
>   directory "/Users/yoni/opower/workspace/intellij_project_root"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory

The problem is that the Hive Server is running in-memory, but relies upon local installation of Hive in order to run. For my project to be self-contained, I need the Hive services to be embedded, including the HDFS and MapReduce clusters. I've tried starting up a Hive server using the same Spring method and pointing it at [MiniDFSCluster](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster.html) and [MiniMRCluster](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MiniMRCluster.html), similar to the pattern used in the Hive [QTestUtil](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/QTestUtil.html) source and in [HBaseTestUtility](http://people.apache.org/~psmith/hbase/sandbox/hbase/hbase-core/testapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTestingUtility.html). However, I've not been able to get that to work.

After three days of trying to wrangle Hive integration testing, I thought I'd ask the community:

1. How do you recommend I integration test Hive jobs?
2. Do you have a working JUnit example for integration testing Hive jobs using in-memory HDFS, MR, and Hive instances?

Additional resources I've looked at:

- [Hive Unit Testing tutorial](http://dev.bizo.com/2011/04/hive-unit-testing.html)
- [the Spring Hive example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/samples/hive)

Edit:
I am fully aware that working against a Hadoop cluster - whether local or remote - makes it possible to run integration tests against a full-stack Hive instance. The problem, as stated, is that this is not a viable solution for effectively testing Hive workflows.

Comment: Since it's looking for an installation, why not create a RAM disk that you can point it to? Other than that, you'll have to start examining the source to see how it uses the configuration you provide it. Then you can write your own glue to bypass the config, and run the features directly.

Comment: Could you please share an example of your final solution?

Comment: @oby1 should have a patch that adds support, but I don't have access to it.

Comment: I'll open source our JUnit test rule for this as soon as I can.

Comment: @yoni Can you post the complete solution that you ended up with here please? I'm in the exact same situation as you were, and while I have Hive JDBC client working, and the MiniDFSCluster code from below working, when I try to run both together (using "jdbc:hive2:///" URL) for a "CREATE TABLE..." query, I get this:
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Comment: Hi Nishant. Sorry to hear you're having trouble with this. I don't have access to the complete solution, but perhaps @oby1 does.In either case, I'd recommend adding a complete example - perhaps in a separate Stack Overflow question - with your exact setup and full stack trace.

Comment: @oby1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665768/pointing-hiveserver2-to-minimrcluster-for-hive-testing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally one would be able to test hive queries with `LocalJobRunner` rather than resorting to mini-cluster testing.  However, due to [HIVE-3816](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3816) running hive with `mapred.job.tracker=local` results in a call to the hive CLI executable installed on the system (as described in your question).

Until HIVE-3816 is resolved, mini-cluster testing is the only option.  Below is a minimal mini-cluster setup for hive tests that I have tested against CDH 4.4.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

/* Build MiniDFSCluster */
MiniDFSCluster miniDFS = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf).build();

/* Build MiniMR Cluster */
System.setProperty("hadoop.log.dir", "/path/to/hadoop/log/dir"); // MAPREDUCE-2785
int numTaskTrackers = 1;
int numTaskTrackerDirectories = 1;
String[] racks = null;
String[] hosts = null;
miniMR = new MiniMRCluster(numTaskTrackers, miniDFS.getFileSystem().getUri().toString(),
                           numTaskTrackerDirectories, racks, hosts, new JobConf(conf));

/* Set JobTracker URI */
System.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", miniMR.createJobConf(new JobConf(conf)).get("mapred.job.tracker"));
```

There is no need to run a separate hiveserver or hiveserver2 process for testing.  You can test with an embedded hiveserver2 process by setting your jdbc connection URL to `jdbc:hive2:///`

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete example? by that I mean, including the part where set up and execute some queries using HiveInterface maybe? thanks a lot

Comment: Piggybacking on the accepted answer: As of Hive 1.2.0 there is an alternative workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40115876/973963

Answer (score 6):

I come to find one pretty good tool: [HiveRunner](https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner).
It is framework on top of jUnit to test hive scripts.
Under the hood it starts a stand alone HiveServer with in memory HSQL as the metastore.

Comment: Very interesting project. It looks like there are some limitations on Hive versions, but I'll definitely look into it for my next project. For now, I'm leaving @oby1's answer as the best bet, but if people continue to report success with HiveRunner, I'll go ahead and switch.

Comment: Great testing suite but I faced version compatibility issues. We're constrained to hive version 2.0.0 and the version compatibility jumps from hive 1.2.1 to 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented HiveRunner.

https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner

We tested it on Mac and had some trouble with Windows, however with a few changes listed below the util served well.

For windows here are some of the changes that were done in order to have HiveRunner work in windows environment. After these changes unit testing is possible for all Hive queries.

1.Clone the project at https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils to anywhere on your computer, Add a new environment variable, HADOOP_HOME, pointing to the /bin directory of that folder. no forward slashes or spaces allowed.
2.Clone the project at https://github.com/sakserv/hadoop-mini-clusters to anywhere on your computer. Add a new environment variable HADOOP_WINDOWS_LIBS, pointing to the /lib directory of that folder. Again, no forward slashes or spaces allowed.
3.I also installed cygwin, assuming severla win utils for linux might be available through.

This pull on gitbub helped with making it work on windows,
https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner/pull/63

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports embedded mode only in the sense that the RDBMS which stores the meta information for the Hive tables can run locally or on a stand alone server (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient for details). Furthermore, hive with it's accompanying database is merely an orchestrator for a string of MapReduce jobs, which requires the Hadoop framework to be running as well.

I recommend using this virtual machine that has a pre-configured Hadoop stack  http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/ . Hortonworks is one of 2 leading Hadoop distribution providers, so it is well-supported.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitriusan. I am aware that you may install and start an local Hadoop cluster to run against, but I'm looking for something a little bit different. A robust solution is one which does not require anything outside of the control of the integration test. This exists for HBase, which also requires HDFS and MapReduce services to be up, but hasn't yet been properly developed for Hive. The pieces are all there, they just need to be connected (and I don't have time to do the connecting). Whether it's Hortonworks, CDH, or any other flavor of Hadoop shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Your question is hanging unanswered since May, I assume that there is no solution you request (at least in public access). 
Anyway, downvoting for trying to help (and suggesting solution that exists and should work) is not positive.

Comment: Gotcha. The down-vote is because your answer does not represent a solution to the problem. But if that's not grounds for down-voting it, then I suppose my SO etiquette might have been off on that, so thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain of what has changed since the accepted answer in Feb. 2014, but as of Hive 1.2.0, the following works around the issue described by OP:

```
System.setProperty(HiveConf.ConfVars.SUBMITLOCALTASKVIACHILD.varname, "false");
```

Do be aware of the warning given in the config documentation:

> Determines whether local tasks (typically mapjoin hashtable generation
>   phase) runs in separate JVM (true recommended) or not. Avoids the
>   overhead of spawning new JVM, but can lead to out-of-memory issues.

This works around the issue because in `MapredLocalTask.java`:

```
  @Override
  public int execute(DriverContext driverContext) {
    if (conf.getBoolVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.SUBMITLOCALTASKVIACHILD)) {
      // send task off to another jvm
      return executeInChildVM(driverContext);
    } else {
      // execute in process
      return executeInProcess(driverContext);
    }
  }
```

The default config value causes the `executeInChildVM()` method to be called, which literally calls `hadoop jar`. The other code path has so far worked out in my testing. Potential memory issues can likely be resolved by tweaking Java heap configs (Xmx, Xms, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Another Hive JUnit runner is at https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive_test