# Pointing HiveServer2 to MiniMRCluster for Hive Testing

Tags: jdbc, hive, integration-testing

I've been wanting to do Hive integration testing for some of the code that I've been developing. The two major requirements of the testing framework that I need:

1. It needs to work with a Cloudera version of Hive and Hadoop
   (preferably, 2.0.0-cdh4.7.0)
2. It needs to be ***all local***. Meaning, the Hadoop cluster and Hive
   server should start on the beginning of the test, run a few queries,
   and teardown after the test is over.

So I broke this problem down into three parts:

1. Getting code for the HiveServer2 part (I decided to use a JDBC
   connector over a Thrift service client)
2. Getting code for building an in-memory MapReduce cluster (I decided to use MiniMRCluster for this)
3. Setting up both (1) and (2) above to work with each other.

I was able to get (1) out of the way by looking at many resources. Some of these that were very useful are:

- [Cloudera Hadoop Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/ENSVdtuZmIA)
- [Hive JDBC Client Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC)

For (2), I followed this excellent post in StackOverflow:

- [Integration Testing Hive Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719541/integration-testing-hive-jobs)

So far, so good. At this point of time, my pom.xml in my Maven project, on including both above functionalities, looks something like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- START: dependencies for getting MiniMRCluster to work -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.7.0</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.7.0</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: dependencies for getting MiniMRCluster to work -->

    <!-- START: dependencies for getting Hive JDBC to work -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-cli</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-ec</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jpox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpox</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jpox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpox-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-beta-5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: dependencies for getting Hive JDBC to work -->
</dependencies>
```

Now I'm on step (3). I tried running the following code:

```
@Test
    public void testHiveMiniDFSClusterIntegration() throws IOException, SQLException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        /* Build MiniDFSCluster */
        MiniDFSCluster miniDFS = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf).build();

        /* Build MiniMR Cluster */
        System.setProperty("hadoop.log.dir", "/Users/nishantkelkar/IdeaProjects/" +
                "nkelkar-incubator/hive-test/target/hive/logs");
        int numTaskTrackers = 1;
        int numTaskTrackerDirectories = 1;
        String[] racks = null;
        String[] hosts = null;
        MiniMRCluster miniMR = new MiniMRCluster(numTaskTrackers, miniDFS.getFileSystem().getUri().toString(),
                numTaskTrackerDirectories, racks, hosts, new JobConf(conf));

        System.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", miniMR.createJobConf(
                new JobConf(conf)).get("mapred.job.tracker"));

        try {
            String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Connection hiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hive2:///", "", "");
        Statement stm = hiveConnection.createStatement();

        // now create test tables and query them
        stm.execute("set hive.support.concurrency = false");
        stm.execute("drop table if exists test");
        stm.execute("create table if not exists test(a int, b int) row format delimited fields terminated by ' '");
        stm.execute("create table dual as select 1 as one from test");
        stm.execute("insert into table test select stack(1,4,5) AS (a,b) from dual");
        stm.execute("select * from test");
    }
```

My hope was that (3) would be solved by the following line of code from the above method:

```
    Connection hiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hive2:///", "", "");
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:161)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:150)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:207)
    at com.ask.nkelkar.hive.HiveUnitTest.testHiveMiniDFSClusterIntegration(HiveUnitTest.java:54)
```

Can anyone please let me know what I need to do in addition/what I'm doing wrong to get this to work?

P.S. I looked at [HiveRunner](https://github.com/klarna/HiveRunner) and [hive_test](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive_test) projects as options, but I wasn't able to get these to work with Cloudera versions of Hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is failing at the first `create table` statement.  Hive is unhelpfully suppressing the following error message:

```
file:/user/hive/warehouse/test is not a directory or unable to create one
```

Hive is attempting to use the default warehouse directory `/user/hive/warehouse` which doesn't exist on your filesystem.  You could create the directory, but for testing you'll likely want to override the default value.  For example:

```
import static org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.ConfVars;
...
System.setProperty(ConfVars.METASTOREWAREHOUSE.toString(), "/Users/nishantkelkar/IdeaProjects/" +
            "nkelkar-incubator/hive-test/target/hive/warehouse");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying on this thread! It's not giving me that error anymore now. You are right, it needs to see that /warehouse folder to proceed. I wish Hive were more verbose semantically with it's error messages.

Comment: Here's a followup question on this post. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look. Thank you! -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851444/hive-integration-testing-insert-into-not-working